# why am i not getting the data of record and just lable in visualforce page?

Tags: salesforce, apex, apex-code, visualforce

attched is my output

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5kj5.png)

Bolow is my visulforce Page and apex page
i am expecting output as a single record in 2 column and has next and previous button to next and previous record.

```
//apex
public with sharing class MyController 
{
    public list<Patient__c> objectList = new List<Patient__c>();
    public list<Patient__c> currentObject {get; set;}
    public integer i;
    public MyController(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller) {myAction();}
    
    public string selectedValue {get; set;}
    public boolean myBoolean {get; set;}    
    
    public void myAction()
    {
        if ( selectedValue == 'List View') { myBoolean = True; }
        else { myBoolean = False ;}
    } 
    
    public Patient__c getCurrentObject()
    {
    return currentObject[i];
    }
    
    public void goToPrevious(){
    if (i>0){i--;}
    }
    
    public void goToNext() {
        if (i < currentObject.size() - 1) {
            i++;
        }
    }    
   /* public void goToRecord (Id recordId) {
        for (Integer i = 0; i < objectList.size(); i++) {
            if (objectList[i].Id == recordId) {
                i = i;
                break; 
            } 
        }
    } */



    
}
```

Below is my visualforce page code.

```
<apex:page standardController="Patient__c" extensions="MyController" recordSetVar="Patients">
<apex:pageBlock title="Patient Records...!!!">
    <apex:form >
    <div align='center' style=' color:blue;font-size:10px '>
            Your selection is {!selectedValue}
    </div>
    <apex:selectList label="View Type"  value="{!selectedValue}" size="1">
            <apex:selectOption itemvalue="Standared View" itemLabel="Standared View"/>
            <apex:selectOption itemvalue="List View" itemLabel="List View"/>   
            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!myAction}" >                 
        </apex:actionSupport>
    </apex:selectList>
    </apex:form>
<apex:pageBlock rendered="{!myBoolean}"> 
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Patients}" var="Pa" >
    <apex:column value="{!Pa.Name}"/>
    <apex:column value="{!Pa.Contact_Number__c}"/>
    <apex:column value="{!Pa.Email__c}"/>
    <apex:column value="{!Pa.Age__c}"/>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
<apex:pageBlock title="Standared View" rendered="{!!myBoolean}"> 
    <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2">
        <apex:outputField value="{!Patient__c.Name}"/>    
        <apex:outputField value="{!Patient__c.Age__c}"/>            
        <apex:outputField value="{!Patient__c.Email__c}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    <apex:form >
            <apex:commandButton value="Previous" action="{!goToPrevious}" />
            <apex:commandButton value="Next" action="{!goToNext}"/>           
    </apex:form> 
</apex:pageBlock>    
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

I am expecting as a single record showing page where have next and previous button to go net and previous record.

Comment: You didn't do anything with StandardSetController passed to you so by default it shows whatever the last listview you used shows. Go to Patients tab, what do you see? An empty listview? Maybe "recently viewed" that's empty?

Comment: sir list view i have selected is all.

Comment: Do you have Profile/Permission Set permissions, at least Read to these fields. I mean StandardSetController is powerful, you don't even need much apex to achieve something. Check https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_sosc_pagination.htm and next example with pagination